# data.table trouble aggregating data with factor in key

Tags: r, data.table

I'm getting some weird results when I try to aggregate a data.table with a factor in the key.  I've simplified my problem to this example.

```
#v1, v2 as character vectors
dt<-data.table(grp=c(1,1,2,2), v1=c("a","a","a","b"), v2=c("a","a","b","b"))
dt[,list(length(which(v1==v2))), by=list(grp,v2)]
   grp v2 V1
1:   1  a  2
2:   2  b  1

#v1, v2 as factor vectors
dt<-data.table(grp=c(1,1,2,2), v1=as.factor(c("a","a","a","b")), v2=as.factor(c("a","a","b","b")))
dt[,list(length(which(v1==v2))), by=list(grp,v2)]
   grp v2 V1
1:   1  a  0
2:   2  b  0
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?  Shouldn't the two statements above give the same result?  Thanks

Edit: I'm using data.table version 1.9.2

Comment: What version of `data.table` are you using. On a relatively newly installed version of 1.9.3 I the same results regardless of factor/character

Comment: Good point.. It seems that when `v2` is included in `by` it is treated as numeric but `v1` is still a factor in the comparison (in `j`) so the comparison always returns FALSE, because of how `==` works for factors... So I guess you should try and coerce factor variables to numeric, i.e. change `v1==v2` to `as.numeric(v1)==v2`.